# Tailwindcss ignoring [attribute=value] Selector

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In my tailwind file I have lines like

```css
@layer utilities {
...
  li[aria-disabled='true'],
  li[aria-disabled='true'] > div {
    @apply pointer-events-none select-none opacity-50 !important;
  }
}
```

The same class not getting built in production. what could be the reason?

No, I have no other mechanisms to add `class` to the same `li` as it generated from another plugin.